# how to include http,fs modules inside node webkit

Tags: angularjs, node.js, node-webkit

I am creating a simple node web kit app. I have form with input type, on submitting the form i want to save this browsed file into temp folder. How to do this with node web kit.

A sample code will be more help to my studying.

Answer (score 0):

When working with NW you should think in a desktop application workflow, you would not need a server side like creating a http server to receive files, instead you could perform file operations from the 'client' side,

To select the file you could use [File dialogs](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/File-dialogs) this code explain how to select it and require the fs module to work with it:

```
<script>
  // requiring the fs module
  var fs = require('fs');
  function chooseFile(name) {
    var chooser = document.querySelector(name);
    chooser.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
      // this will print the selected file
      console.log(this.value);
      // from here you could use the fs module required above to do whatever you need with the file, read it or write it
    }, false);

    chooser.click();  
  }
  chooseFile('#fileDialog');
</script>
```